# Feature Event has 'null' objects

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

```
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{

    public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

        string sContextNull = (SPContext.Current == null) ? "Context is NULL" : "Context is OK";
        string sFeatureNull = (properties.Feature == null) ? "Feature is NULL" : "Feature is OK";

        // Some code here
        ...
        ...
    {
}
```

The feature has successfully installed (without error in logs). My problem is that **sContextNull** always returns **"Context is NULL"**. And **sFeatureNull** always returns **"Feature is NULL"** too. Is there a way to get not null values of **SPContext.Current** and **properties.Feature**?

Another method **FeatureActivated** returns **Context is NULL** and **Feature is OK**. WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably **properties.Feature** in method **FeatureInstalled** is a bug. I have tried the next code and it works for me:

```
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{    
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {    
        string sFeatureNull = (properties.Feature == null) ? "Feature is NULL" : "Feature is OK";

        // Some code here
        ...
        ...
    {
}
```

this method return **Feature is OK**.

Please avoid using **properties.Feature** in the method **FeatureInstalled** and **FeatureUninstalling**!!!

Answer (score 2):

SPContext.Current

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontext.current.aspx

`Gets the context of the current HTTP request in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.`

`SPFeatureReceiver.FeatureInstalled` is executing when a feature is installed into a farm, which is done with a deploy/install command from stsadm or powershell, which then usually triggers the timer job to do the work. At this point there is no HTTP request, so SPContext.Current returns null.

Comment: Thanks! What is about **properties.Feature**?

Comment: you could try debugging the event http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chriskeyser/archive/2010/07/26/debugging-a-featureinstalled-event.aspx

Comment: and this seems to be similar to your problem http://suguk.org/forums/thread/16667.aspx

Comment: the same problem http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/e9c72eef-5106-48e0-83a2-ff53754a4881. Nobody knows the answer

Comment: properties.Feature is null in FeatureInstalled. For the purposes that you're trying to use it, to get at properties.Feature.Parent, it's not useful anyhow. The suggestion below -- use FeatureActivated instead -- is probably your best bet. If you're doing something that doesn't require a SPSite or SPWeb context, FeatureInstalled will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the web which contains this feature so try to use

```
(properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
```

It works fine with me

Note:Try to cast it to SPSite if the feature scope is site